# How to implement "Do Not Show" check box in splash window using Telerik RadWindow?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, splash-screen, radwindow, dynamic-splash-screen

I am trying to implement a splash window using telerik Radwindow. I have to implement the "Do not show" check box in the splash window so that if user click on that, the splash window will not be shown till the next release. A sample code of mine is shown below

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" Width="660px" Height="540px">  
<Windows>  
    <telerik:RadWindow ID="Win1" VisibleOnPageLoad="true" runat="server" VisibleStatusbar="false"  
        Animation="Fade" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" VisibleTitlebar="false" Behaviors="None"  
        Modal="false">  
        <ContentTemplate>  
            <img src="Images/Image.jpg" />

            <telerik:RadButton ID="radButton" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClicked="closeRadWindow" AutoPostBack="false"></telerik:RadButton>
        </ContentTemplate>  
    </telerik:RadWindow>  
</Windows>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the client-side handler of the button create a cookie with the desired expiration. You can modify it later by name even from your server code if you like.

Then, use the OnClientBeforeShow event to check for that cookie and if it exists - cancel the event to prevent the dialog from showing up.

I also found this rather old KB article that may still work and you may find useful: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/radconfirm-with-do-not-show-again-option

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain it futhur. I found the codes are too complex for me to understand